# usbManager openDevice call fails after several hundred successful attempts

Tags: usb, hid

I'm using usbmanager class to manage USB host on my android 4.1.1 machine.
all seems to work quite well for a few hundreds of transactions until (after ~ 900 transactions) opening the device fails, returning null without exception.
Using a profiler it doesn't seem to be a matter of memory leakage.

this is how I initialize the communication from my main activity (doing this once):

```
public class MainTestActivity extends Activity {

private BroadcastReceiver m_UsbReceiver = null;
private PendingIntent mPermissionIntent = null;
UsbManager m_manager=null;
DeviceFactory m_factory = null;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);

    filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED);
    m_UsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction(); 

          if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED.equals(action)) {
                UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice)intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                if (device != null) {
                    // call your method that cleans up and closes communication with the device
                    Log.v("BroadcastReceiver", "Device Detached");
                }
            }

        }
    };
    registerReceiver(m_UsbReceiver, filter);

   m_manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);

   m_factory = new DeviceFactory(this,mPermissionIntent);

}
```

and this is the code of my test:

```
ArrayList<DeviceInterface> devList = m_factory.getDevicesList();
if ( devList.size() > 0){
      DeviceInterface devIf = devList.get(0);
      UsbDeviceConnection connection; 
          try 
    {
        connection = m_manager.openDevice(m_device);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

The test will work OK for 900 to 1000 calls and after this the following call will return null (without exception):

```
UsbDeviceConnection connection; 
try 
{
  connection = m_manager.openDevice(m_device);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You might just run out of file handles, a typical limit would be 1024 open files per process.
Try calling `close()` on the `UsbDeviceConnection`, [see doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDeviceConnection.html#close%28%29).

The `UsbDeviceConnection` object has allocated system ressources - e.g. a file descriptor - which will be released only on garbage collection in your code. But in this case you run out of ressources before you run out of memory - which means the garbage collector is not invoked yet.

Comment: Thanks Turbo J, your answer was on the right track. I closed and made sure to release the usb end points. problem solved.

Comment: Did I understand you correct? 1024 files per process? Does it means it doesn't matter how many times I reopen connection and release device if I don't close any connection?

Answer (score 0):

I had opendevice fail on repeated runs on android 4.0 even though I open only once in my code. I had some exit paths that did not close the resources and I had assumed the OS would free it on process termination.

However there seems to be some issue with release of resources on process termination -I used to have issues even when I terminated and launched a fresh process.
I finally ensured release of resources on exit and made the problem go away.